# how android studio gradle compile external cpp sources?

Tags: c++, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

It's easy to compile c++ sources to xxx.so following Android Template.
But it's weird when I move the cpp folder and edit externalNativeBuild.
step1:
When I move cpp folder in another place, and modify externalNativeBuild.cmake.path, it works fine.(sync -> clean project -> rebuild project)
step2:
When I move cpp folder in another place again, and modify externalNativeBuild.cmake.path, it not worked any more.[image]

I deleted the build folder and rebuild, but error occured also.

My gradle environment is 6.5   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip

So Needing more config in build.gradle? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I deleted the build folder and rebuild, but error occured also.

Try to delete `app/.cxx` folder, it might help. Also sometimes `Build->Rebuild Project` helps.

Comment: delete app/.cxx works. How can gradle detect the modification and clear app/.cxx automatically?

Comment: I work with AndroidStudio and it mostly works well except for some exceptional cases. When I make a modification in the cmake files, I first check that modification with ```Build-> Refresh Linked C ++ Projects``` without recompiling all the stuff, and that's basically enough to apply and check the cmake changes.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But `Build->Refresh Linked C++ Projects` not work for folder position modification. Luckily, folder position is not modified frequently.